# Create a symlink using ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, symlink

I am trying to create a symlink for the created file but I get an error like `File exists - (/etc/nginx/sites-available/sushant.com, /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sushant.com) (Errno::EEXIST)`

Here is my code

```
    require 'fileutils'
open('/etc/hosts') do |f|
  matches = []
  vhosts = []
  f.readlines.each do |lines|
    matches << lines if lines =~ /.*.com/
  end
  matches.each do |val|
    val.split.each do |x|
      vhosts << x if x =~ /.*.com/
    end
  end
  vhosts.each do |domain|
#put the path to sites-enabled
    unless File.file? "/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{domain}"
      open("/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{domain}", 'w') do |g|
        g << "server { \n"
        g << "\tlisten 80 default_server;\n"
        g << "\tlisten [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;\n"
        g << "\troot /usr/share/nginx/html;\n"
        g << "\tindex index.html index.htm;\n"
        g << "\tserver_name localhost;\n"
        g << "\tlocation / {\n"
        g << "\t\ttry_files $uri $uri/ =404;\n"
        g << "\t}\n"
        g << "}\n"
        g << "server {\n"
        g << "\tpassenger_ruby /path/to/ruby;\n"
        g << "\trails_env development;\n"
        g << "\tlisten 80;\n"
        g << "\tserver_name #{domain};\n"
        g << "\troot /usr/share/nginx/html/#{domain}/public;\n"
        g << "\tpassenger_enabled on;\n"
        g << "}\n"
      end
      File.symlink  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{domain}", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{domain}"
    end
  end

  p vhosts
end
```

Why is the EEXIST error occurs after I run the script? Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Your second string is single-quoted.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev , fixed it but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: As an aside, you can use `File.write(filename, contents)` to write a string to a file, and strings can be multiline, no need to do it in this messy way. Like this: https://gist.github.com/passcod/8b62a962861b67dac6b2

Comment: The error message mentions `/opt/` as second argument, which does not seem right given the script provided. Is this the actual error from the current code, and if not, can you provide the current one, fully if possible?

Comment: Silly question, but: are you sure the `sites-enabled/sushant.com` etc files don't already exist? If you've run this script before, they could have been generated in a previous pass.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli no they do not exist, I have made sure about that.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli , the file gets created first then it is symlinked. Is not that how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that I should have placed `File.symlink  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{domain}", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{domain}"` first then the action to create the file.